# Добавление фото на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать функцию добавления фото на сайте при помощи html или jQuery? Имеется ввиду не с помощью кода, а именно на самом сайте? Возможно ли?

Answer (score 2):

Что именно имеется ввиду  не с помощью кода , а на самом сайте ? Нужен код что бы на сайте появилась кнопка добавить картинку и с помощью нее картинка появлялась на сайте ?

Comment: Да, именно так, в голове как то понятнее звучало

Comment: Непонятно для чего нужно. Аватарку загрузить или фото в галерею добавить. 
https://wp-kama.ru/id_9026/jquery-ajax-zagruzka-fajlov-na-server.html  может это вам подойдет. Конкретики мало в вашем вопросе что и для чего

Comment: "загрузить картинку jquery  "   вот так в гугле вопрос задайте. Что то да подберете  вариантов много готовых